# Migration of entries to a different channel. Deleting old channel deletes moved entries

Tags: migration

I've written a migration which successfully moves entries to a new section. The problem is that if you delete the old empty section, the moved entries are removed with it.

**Before Migration:**

Section 1 > EntryX

Section 2

**After migration**

Section 1 >

Section 2 > EntryX

Delete Section 1 results in EntryX being deleted.

What am I missing:

```
<?php

namespace craft\contentmigrations;

use Craft;
use craft\db\Migration;
use craft\elements\Entry;


/**
 * m231105_184930_resourcesLBMHToGeneral migration.
 */
class m231105_184930_resourcesLBMHToGeneral extends Migration
{
    
    public function moveEntriesDb() {

        // Moving entries from section
        $OLD_SECTION_ID = 31;

        // Moving entries to section
        $NEW_SECTION_ID = 54;

        // Change entry types
        $OLD_ENTRY_TYPE = 63;

        // Change entry types
        $NEW_ENTRY_TYPE = 101;


        // $industry[] = 331869;
        // $entries = Entry::find()->section('resourcesLbmh')->all();


        $lbhm = Entry::find()->section('industries')->id(331869)->one();
        $lbhmProdIds = $lbhm->relatedProducts->status(['live', 'pending', 'expired','disabled'])->ids();
        $buisnessApp = Entry::find()->section('industries')->id(717402)->one();
        $buisnessAppProdIds = $buisnessApp->relatedProducts->status(['live', 'pending', 'expired','disabled'])->ids();

        $industryArray = [$lbhm->id];

        $entries = Entry::find()->section('resourcesLbmh')->site('*')->status(['live', 'pending', 'expired','disabled']);

        echo "Saving entries with no relatedProducts set..." . PHP_EOL;

        foreach($entries->relatedProducts(':empty:')->all() as $entry) {

            // Update Entry
            $entry->setFieldValues(['relatedIndustries' => $industryArray]);
            $success = \Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry);

            if ($success) {
                echo 'Set entry ' . $entry . ' relatedIndustries to ' . implode(',', $industryArray) . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "'.$entry->title.'"', __METHOD__);
            }
        }
        
        echo "Saving entries with related products" . PHP_EOL;

        foreach($entries->relatedProducts(':notempty:')->all() as $entry) {
            $industryArray = [];
            $relatedProductIds = [];

            foreach ($entry->relatedProducts as $product) {
                $relatedProductIds[] = $product->id;
            }

            if (count(array_intersect($relatedProductIds, $lbhmProdIds)) > 0) {
                $industryArray[] = $lbhm->id;
            }

            if (count(array_intersect($relatedProductIds, $buisnessAppProdIds)) > 0) {
                $industryArray[] = $buisnessApp->id;
            }

            // Update Entry
            $entry->setFieldValues(['relatedIndustries' => $industryArray]);
            $success = \Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry);

            if ($success) {
                echo 'Set entry ' . $entry . ' relatedIndustries to ' . implode(',', $industryArray) . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "'.$entry->title.'"', __METHOD__);
            }     
        }

        $this->update('entries', ['sectionId' => $NEW_SECTION_ID], 'sectionId = ' . $OLD_SECTION_ID);
        $this->update('entryversions',['sectionId' => $NEW_SECTION_ID],'sectionId = ' . $OLD_SECTION_ID);
        $this->update('entries',['typeId' => $OLD_ENTRY_TYPE],'typeId = ' . $NEW_ENTRY_TYPE);

        echo '------------------------------------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Migrated entries from section:' . $OLD_SECTION_ID . ' to '. $NEW_SECTION_ID . PHP_EOL;

    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function safeUp(): bool
    {
        $this->moveEntriesDb();
        echo 'Finished!' . PHP_EOL;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function safeDown(): bool
    {
        echo "m231105_184930_resourcesLBMHToGeneral cannot be reverted.\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```